# Why do `initializer_list<pair>` and `initializer_list<tuple>` behave differently?

Tags: c++, tuples, initializer-list, std-pair

The following code compiles and runs :

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

void ext( std::initializer_list<std::pair<double, std::vector<double> >> myList )
{
    //Do something
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main(void) {
    ext( { {1.0, {2.0, 3.0, 4.0} } } );
    return 0;
}
```

While this one does not :

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

void ext( std::initializer_list<std::tuple<double, std::vector<double> >> myList )
{
    //Do something
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main(void) {
    ext( { {1.0, {2.0, 3.0, 4.0} } } );
    return 0;
}
```

The sole difference is that in the first case the `ext()` function takes an argument of type `initializer_list<pair>` (works) while the other uses `initializer_list<tuple>` (does not work). However, [cplusplus.com states that](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/)

> Pairs are a particular case of tuple.

So why does one code work and the other not ?

---

## Additional information

The error outputted by clang++ in the second case is :

```
main.cpp:33:2: error: no matching function for call to 'ext'
      ext( { {1.0, {2.0, 3.0, 4.0} } } );
      ^~~
main.cpp:7:6: note: candidate function not viable: cannot convert initializer list argument to 'std::tuple<double,
      std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >'
void ext( std::initializer_list<std::tuple<double, std::vector<double> >> myList )
      ^
1 error generated.
```

while g++ outputs :

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:33:35: error: converting to ‘std::tuple<double, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >’ from initializer list would use explicit constructor ‘constexpr std::tuple<_T1, _T2>::tuple(const _T1&, const _T2&) [with _T1 = double; _T2 = std::vector<double>]’
  ext( { {1.0, {2.0, 3.0, 4.0} } } );
                                   ^
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

cplusplus.com is not a very good site, because it is full of false statement like "Pairs are a particular case of tuple."  You could use `cppreference` instead.   In fact pair is not a particular case of tuple.

It's considered now that `tuple` is the better design; `pair` is quite a lot older and can't be changed now because of backwards compatibility.

The error message indicates that the difference is that `tuple` has an `explicit` constructor, but `pair` doesn't.

This means you need to mention the class name when constructing a tuple:

```
 ext( { std::tuple<double,std::vector<double>>{1.0, {2.0, 3.0, 4.0} } } );
```

---

This will be changed in C++17: the constructor of `tuple` will be explicit if and only if one of the tuple's types is class type with explicit constructor. gcc 6 already implements this feature.  (Credit - Jonathan Wakely). See [N4387](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4387.html)

Comment: N.B. the `explicit`-ness of tuple's constructor is now conditional on the argument types, and the example code will be valid in C++17 (and compiles today with GCC 6).

Comment: @JonathanWakely thanks for that info . I was just wondering how I would answer if OP asked "why is it explicit, this seems annoying" and I didn't have any good answer

Comment: @M.M thanks for your help ! Indeed, that would be a good question…